# Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT (index):182 TypeError: Failed to fetch at updateChart

Tags: node.js

I was trying to build a web app to plot temperature data sent from esp32 using wifi.h module.

to get temperature readings from server side i used fetch('http://localhost:3000/data')...... and here is the code i have written in script tag

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = function () {


        var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer",{
            title :{
                text: "Live Data"
            },
            axisX: {
                title: "Axis X Title"
            },
            axisY: {
                title: "Units"
            },
            data: [{
                type: "line",
                dataPoints : dps
            }]
        });

        chart.render();
        var xVal = dps.length + 1;
        var yVal = 0;
        var updateInterval = 1000;

        var updateChart = function () {

          let i = 10;

         fetch('http://localhost:3000/data').then(response => response.text()).then(data => {yVal = Number(data);}).catch(error => console.error(error));

          dps.push({x:xVal,y:yVal});

            xVal++;
            if (dps.length >  10 )
            {
                dps.shift();
            }

            chart.render();



  };

  setInterval(function(){updateChart()}, updateInterval);
  }
  </script>
```

and here is the code i used for for server-side.

```
var curr_temperature = 0;

const express = require('express');
const serv = express();


serv.get("/data", function(req, res){

    res.status(200).send(String(curr_temperature));

});

serv.listen(3000);



var http = require('http');
  var server = http.createServer(function (req, res) {


    if (req.method === 'POST' && req.url === '/post_data') {
        let body = '';
        req.on('data', function (data) {
            body += data;
        });
        req.on('end', function () {

           //console.log(body);

           curr_temperature = Number(body);



           //res.end('ok');
        });
    } else {
        res.end('Not Found');

    }
});

server.listen(8080, function(){
  console.log("Server is listening");
});
```

so, i was using port 8080 to receive values from esp32 and 3000/data for sending data to the graph for dynamic plotting. It was working fine locally but when i deployed it data sent is not being plotted. And just to be clear i have changed url in fetch('http://my_website:3000/data'). But i was showing typeerror enable to fetch.
hope I was clear enough. can someone correct me if i am wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, it got resolved after removing the port in the URL
`fetch('https://my_website/data');`.